# How can I use apply or sapply in carrying out multiple tests?

Tags: r

My goal is to do chi-square test with reduced time.

```
data <- data.frame(
  sex = factor(c("M", "F", "M")),
  ageid = factor(c(8, 6, 7)),
  married = factor(c(2, 1, 2)),
  cagv_typ = factor(c("non-primary", "primary", "non-primary")),
  sq5_1 = factor(c(1, 1, 1)),
  sq5_2 = factor(c(0, 1, 0))
)
```

Among this dataframe, sex and married are variable, and the rest of them are outcomes. Acutually I have more than 10 outcome variables and 5 subgroup variables.

At first, I made the following codes based on the example shown here
https://epirhandbook.com/en/simple-statistical-tests.html#chi-squared-test-1

```
library(rstatix)
chis_test <- function(data, var1, var2){
  result <- data %>%
    tabyl({{var1}}, {{var2}}) %>%
    select(-1) %>% 
    chisq_test()
  return(result)
}
```

Next, I tried to get all possible combinations using expand_grid():

```
combo <- expand_grid(x = names(data)[c(1, 3)], y = names(data)[-c(1, 3)])
```

And the result shows as follows (other acutal variables shown as well):

```
             x          y
1      cagv_typ      ageid
2           sex      ageid
3   cset_typ_bi      ageid
4     lv_eas_bi      ageid
5    und_con_bi      ageid
6    sup_ard_bi      ageid
7    job_inf_bi      ageid
8      cagv_typ    married
9           sex    married
10  cset_typ_bi    married
11    lv_eas_bi    married
12   und_con_bi    married
13   sup_ard_bi    married
14   job_inf_bi    married
```

I also tried one combination of sex and cagv_tpy with codes:

```
chis_test(sq_catvar, sex, cagv_typ)
```

And it returned the result I wanted:

```
n  statistic  p      df    method        p.signif 
267  55.8   7.87e-14  1 Chi-square test   ****
```

But when I use apply(), it failed:

```
apply(combo, 1, function(x) chis_test(data, x[1], x[2]))
```

I wonder what is going wrong. Thank you in advance!

Best wishes

Comment: `combo` != `combos`

Comment: It is a typo when I editted this question.

Comment: Could you give an example of just one test combination?

Comment: seems you need `lapply(data[c(1,3)],\(x)lapply(data[-c(1,3)], \(y)chisq.test(table(x,y))))
`

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you for your comment. I have posted the example of test combination.

Comment: THAT is results from expand grid. Not result from running your function on one combination

Comment: @Onyambu Sorry for the confusion. I have updated my question with adding the example.

Comment: try the code i gave above

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you so much, it works. BTW, I want to ask two questions.
1. as it produces a large list, how can I extract the p value to put into an excel or csv file?
2. I think I lack much in basic knowledge especially in the use of lapply, is there any book or website you recommend?
Best wishes

Comment: in that case use `sapply` ie `sapply(data[c(1,3)], \(x)sapply(data[-c(1,3)], \(y)chisq.test(table(x,y))$p.value))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Onyambu's comments, here is a tidyverse approach (maybe a bit easier to follow / understand):

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

data <- data.frame(
  sex = factor(c("M", "F", "M")),
  ageid = factor(c(8, 6, 7)),
  married = factor(c(2, 1, 2)),
  cagv_typ = factor(c("non-primary", "primary", "non-primary")),
  sq5_1 = factor(c(1, 1, 1)),
  sq5_2 = factor(c(0, 1, 0))
)

var_names_x <- c("sex", "married")
var_names_y <- names(data)[!names(data) %in% var_names_x]
data_var_names <- tidyr::expand_grid(x_var = var_names_x, y_var = var_names_y)

purrr::map2(.x = data_var_names$x_var,
            .y = data_var_names$y_var,
            .f = ~chisq.test(table(data[[.x]], data[[.y]])))
```

Edit:
You asked for a way to extract the p-values nicely. In order to do this we can save the results of `map2()` and use `sapply()` or `map_dbl()`.

```
res <- purrr::map2(.x = data_var_names$x_var,
                   .y = data_var_names$y_var,
                   .f = ~chisq.test(table(data[[.x]], data[[.y]])))

data_var_names$pval <- unlist(sapply(res, "[", "p.value"))
## OR:
data_var_names$pval <- map_dbl(res, "p.value")
```

Resulting in:

```
> data_var_names
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  x_var   y_var     pval
  <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
1 sex     ageid    0.223
2 sex     cagv_typ 0.665
3 sex     sq5_1    0.564
4 sex     sq5_2    0.665
5 married ageid    0.223
6 married cagv_typ 0.665
7 married sq5_1    0.564
8 married sq5_2    0.665
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Meanwhile, I found it produced a large list, from which it is hard for me to extract p value one by one. Is there any approach to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited my original answer to hopefully adress this. Does it suffice?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You advice works so well, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, I met a problem. Actually, I found the frequencies of an outcome in two subgroups are 0, but p value is <0.05. I don't know what is going wrong. Can you help me?